# jQuery Mobile ajax loading spinner not working

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-mobile

Building a jQuery Mobile app in DreamweaverCS6. Have a an ul with multiple links calling html pages each hold a quiz. The "quiz" page is a jqm page with a javascript file doing all the work of the quiz. Everything works fine, but when you click on the li quiz button to load the page it takes a little while to load and the ajax loading spinner is not showing up. This is a problem because you don't know if the app has frozen or not. Any thoughts on how to force the spinner to show while loading the page?

```
 <div data-role="content">  

    <ul data-role="listview">


    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
            <li data-role="list-divider">Quizzes</li>
            <li><a href="quiz1.html">Quiz 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="quiz2.html">Quiz 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="quiz3.html">Quiz 3</a></li>
```

Comment: It think you'll have to link to your working example, what you've posted is cookie-cutter jQM code. Are you getting any errors in your console?

Comment: No, everything works just fine but there is a delay of 3-5 seconds for the page to load.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the

```
$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
```

and

```
$.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
```

You can refer http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/config/loadingMessageTextVisible.html for proper usage.

You can reduce the page loading speed by actually writing the contents of each pages in particular div tags like :

```
<div data-role="page" id="quiz1"> 
    <div data-role="header">...</div> 
    <div data-role="content">...</div> 
    <div data-role="footer">...</div> 
</div>
```

You can load this page as :

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
        <li data-role="list-divider">Quizzes</li>
        <li><a href="#quiz1">Quiz 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#quiz2">Quiz 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#quiz3">Quiz 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

This will greatly reduce the page loading time and speed up your app.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have your code, those links will do a full refresh, abd not showing the jqm spinner.

What you can do is change a page programatically, which uses the jqm spinner for transitioning pages. More info http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/api/methods.html - changePage ($.mobile.changePage())

The idea is to have yours

as follows:

```
<li><a class="quiz1">Quiz 1<a><li>
<script>
    $(document).on('pageinit', '.quiz1', function() {
        $.mobile.changePage('quiz1.html');
    });
</script>
```

hope you get the idea...